# TYPO3 Blog - cannot select category to blog entry because there are not shown

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I'm using TYPO3 10.4.22 and EXT:blog 11.0.2.

Currently I'm facing the problem, that in a blog entry I cannot select a category as they are not shown.

[image: no category available to select]

In the frontend, the categories I added are shown in the category wizard.
[image: here categories are shwon]

Comment: cross post: https://github.com/TYPO3GmbH/blog/issues/247

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Page-TSConfig if you've set the value for `TCEFORM.pages.categories.PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID` to the correct folder with your blog categories.

See step 5 of the [Manual Setup Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/p/t3g/blog/main/en-us/Setup/Manual/Index.html) for details.

Comment: Hi Peter,this was the step I missed. Did not remember that I did this on another page were I am using the Blog as well. Too long ago :-) It is working now, thanks for your help.